# openproject package install error on centos 7 x64

Tags: centos, rpm

```
Running transaction

Installing : openproject-4.2.6-1439479767.f7bca92.centos7.x86_64 1/1

Error unpacking rpm package openproject-4.2.6-1439479767.f7bca92.centos7.x86_64

error: unpacking of archive failed on file /opt/openproject/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/fog-1.23.0/tests/aws/requests/iam/role_tests.rb;55e16dff: cpio: read

Verifying : openproject-4.2.6-1439479767.f7bca92.centos7.x86_64 1/1

Failed: openproject.x86_64 0:4.2.6-1439479767.f7bca92.centos7
```

Tried many times, but keeps saying that there is an error unpacking.

ref: https://www.openproject.org/open-source/packaged-installation/packaged-installation-core/

Comment: Check if the package was correctly downloaded. Try to download it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the package you downloaded is damaged. Assuming you're following the `CentOS 7` instructions, it should solve by doing the following:

```
yum clean all
yum uninstall openproject
yum install openproject
```

**EDIT**: Just tried to install this by myself in a fresh installed CentOS7 box, and yes, it fails. It's not your fault, it's the package that is corrupt. You may want to warn about it on a openproject mail list.

Seems that if you install version 4.1 instead of 4.2 it works. For that, you have to change your repo to:

```
[openproject]
name=Repository for opf/openproject application.
baseurl=https://rpm.packager.io/gh/opf/openproject/centos6/stable/4.1
enabled=1
```

Comment: these is no purge thing..

Comment: I updated my answer. The first command might fail if the package didn't install completely, but the second one should work.

Comment: sorry man, even if I did that, the same result, the rpm seems corrupted..

Comment: Can you try running `yum clean all` **previously** to run the `yum install openproject`?

Comment: unfortunately, it is the same behaviour

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: Kindly note that when I face that problem, I started reverting to the fresh install snapshot. Any way, it is not a yum issue, rather it seems a corrupted rpm..

Comment: I updated my answer with a repo that works. It's version 4.1 instead of 4.2, but it installs and works well as far as I could try. Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe that CE edition is working fine, v4.2